# Working with Swift and Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data

[image]This is more of a generalized question as I have yet to write the code for the question I am asking. Before I get started writing the code I wanted to make sure I am on the right track and possibly getting suggestions for better ways to do what I want to do. Basically right now I have a core data model setup in a way that I think is correct for what I am trying to do and just need some guidance on a very specific part of the code but want to make sure overall I created it correctly.

The first part to the question is more of a clarification on how relationships work in core data. Right now I have 5 entities and to make sure I have the correct idea on how it works I will use a few examples to make sure I am on the right track.

So lets save I have an entity I called name. Within that Name entity that contains only a name attribute. Next I have an entity that has classes, that each have a boolean of true or false to determine which class it is. These 2 are related in a inverse relationship of Name entity having a to one relationship and the Classes having a to many relationship because multiple names can have multiple classes but each name can only have 1 class. If I am right on this one that means I full understand core data relationships!

Now the second part of the question is related to the booleans in the class. I have the Class entity which is like I said a boolean containing a true false set as default to false. When the user selects one of the class buttons before presenting the popover where they actually give the name of the class selected it saves the boolean to true then passes that data over to the popover Name view controller. I am very unsure as to how to do this as it isn't a widely asked question on here nor have I been able to find any info through researching. I am one of those people who needs to actually learn by clear examples....any help with this would be appreciated! Sorry I don't have any example code for this.

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of your class diagram?

Comment: Sure! Sorry I didn't think to do that give me 5 minutes as I am working on something atm.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the data module I created

Comment: Ok so when I present the name to the user in a tableview it will actually also have the data related of the class that the user selected correct? I did my best to try and really grasp core data as a concept. Now as to the second part of the question I had an issue before that I needed apples help directly for because the forums couldn't answer it. Whenever I presented a popover the data wouldn't save. My concern is that the class object will be created but that because it is created before the name it wont save properly...is this a valid concern?

Comment: Also being that I am saving data from different view controllers am I going to have to work with child contexts?

Answer (score 0):

The first part seems correct. The ManagedObject of your Class CoreDataObject should have an NSSet property which will contain the names (as the Class can have multiple names)

For the second part, Core Data uses objects. When you 'get' the data from Core Data it will be a (probably extended) NSManagedObject (named Class in our case). You can send this object as a parameter just as you would do with any other object and use it as you would use any other object :-). For example looping over de NSSet Names

```
func iterateOverNames(someClass: Class) {
    for name: Name in someClass.names {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

You can check these links for more information:

https://realm.io/news/jesse-squires-core-data-swift/

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/index.html

Comment: I think I understand this part lol the first part of core data getting the objects to save was extremely easy to understand but the retrieving/passing data has been a little more difficult for me. If I am understanding correctly the func that you presented as code there loops over all the names and checks the class that each name is? Let's say I have a cell in tableview that has a right detail how would I use this func to present the class that the user is as a detail? I know it would be similar to `if Class("isWarrior") = true { cell.detailtext?.text = "Warrior" } I am still learning`

Comment: I am just unsure of how to actually work with the boolean objects as opposed to most other objects that need to be presented.

Comment: A boolean object is stored as an NSNumber in CoreData. To store it you would need to store an NSNumber. [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];

To use it: someBoolObject.boolValue.

Comment: The code I provided above loops over every name in someClass.names. This way you can use the 'Name' objects stored with your 'Class'.

Comment: `let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("ClassSelection", inManagedObjectContext: classMOC!)
        
        let newObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext:classMOC!)
        
        newObject.setValue(true, forKey: "isWarrior")` is my current code i am using to change the boolean from false to true.